# Pointers to pointers in arrays

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a question about pointers and arrays in C++. I'm not sure exactly what this section of code is doing. As the way I see it iarray is declared as a normal array. However q is being accessed like its a 2d array.

```
    int iarray[10];
    int *p = iarray;
    int **q = &p;
    q[0][2] = 25;
```

And if I change the iarray to:

```
    int iarray[10]{3,2};
    int *p = iarray;
    int **q = &p;
    q[0][2] = 25;

    cout << q[0][0] << endl;
    cout << q[1][0] << endl;
```

The first one will print 3, which I understand as I declared it above. But the second one is blank and I don't understand why.

Comment: 2 is stored in `q[0][1]`, not `q[1][0]`

Comment: Note that dereferencing `q[1]` causes undefined behavior.

Comment: The problem is that I do know what it is doing, but don't know how to articulate it in a meaningful way. But basically, it's sort of trying to construct a de facto 2d array, and then dereference memory that is out of bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look one instruction at a time:

`int iarray[10];` will reserve 10 int-sized bytes in memory. If `sizeof(int) == 4`it will reserve 40 bytes. Let's assume that memory range is set between 0x10 - 0x37.

`int *p = iarray` reserves 4 bytes (if we assume we're running on a 32 bit processor) and stores the starting address to the 40 bytes reserved in the previous instruction. `p` is the shorthand we use to refer to those 4 bytes. Let's say those 4 bytes are stored at 0x50 - 0x53.

`int **q = &p` reserves 4 more bytes which will hold the start address of p (0x50). q can be stored at 0x60-0x63.

The array index operator in c++ on pointers is a shorthand for pointer arithmetic. E.g `q[N]` is the same thing as `*(q + N)`, so, in my exmple, `q[0]` will give you the value held at address 0x60-0x63 which is 0x50.
If you use the index operator again it will apply on the new address (0x50), so `q[0][2]` is equivalent with `p[2]`, which is `iarray[2]`.

`q[1]` is equivalent to `*(q + 1) = *(0x60 + 0x4) =*(0x64)`. If you look above, we never reserver address 0x64, so we're reading from memory we don't own - undefined behaviour.

Comment: Okay I understand this more. Just to be sure the structure of iarray would it be {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} if we had a list of numbers from 1 to 9. Or would the structure being something like this {*p1, *p2, *p3} where *p1 = {1,2,3} , *p2 = {4,5,6}, *p3 = {7,8,9}.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? I don't understand it. Are you referring to   the case where you define iarray as `int iarray[10]{3,2}`? `int iarray[10]{3,2}` reserves 10 contiguous ints and initializes iarray[0] = 3 and iarray[1] = 2.

Comment: My apologies, by saying structure I mean how will the data be presented as an array. As i know a normal 2d array is something like {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}. If an example can be given that will be great thanks. :)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I suspect you're right. If you declare `int arr[3][2]`, the compiler will reserve 6 contiguous ints and store them as 1,2,3,4,5,6.... When you're using the index operator, the compiler will know how to compute the proper offset: [2][1] would be *(arr + 2 * 3 + 1). Since you're new to C++ I recommend using std::vector<std::vector<int>> to represent a matrix - it's much easier to understand and harder to misuse.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take look at this:

```
int iarray[10]; // declare a array of 10 ints
int *p = iarray; // p is used like an alias for iarray, an int[] is also an int*
int **q = &p; //q is a pointer to pointer p
```

`q` points only to a single value. You can think of `q` like an array with just one entry. You could also write it as `int *q[] = { &p };`

So `q[1][0]` is undefined behaviour, since `q[1]` will already be out of bounds.